# Save a static copy of a model in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, angularjs

Now i have something like this, in the view :

```
<input ng-model="kunde" type="text">
```

and a controller trying to save the model to a factory :

```
$scope.setKunde ($scope.kunde) {
    factory.set($scope.kunde);
}
```

The problem now is, that of course everytime I change the model with the input field, the setter function automatically triggers.

Now my question is, how do I save the model from the view in a static way, i.e. for http post requests. I dont want to post a request everytime i change the view.

Thanks

Comment: How does it automatically trigger?

Comment: Is `$scope.kunde` an object, array, or a primitive?  If it is an object or array, you will need to create a copy if you don't want changes to `$scope.kunde` to also change the object/array that you set in factory.

Comment: @rtcherry kunde is an object, and thats exactly what i want to do, everytime i edit the scope object via the input, it triggers the function and the object in the factory gets overwritten. But i want to have the a "snapshot" of that scope object which will not be edited by the change of the input.

Comment: @Bart because the sope object is defined as a parameter of the function, and everytime the scope object is edited by the model input, it triggers.

Comment: Is it possible that i'm maybe looking for something like $destroy ? hm...

Comment: No, you are not looking for $destroy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fail of mine.

If you have a syntax error like this :

```
<button ng-on-click="{{send()}}">
```

which should be looking like this :

```
<button ng-on-click="send()">
```

The method send() is triggered EVERY TIME you use a input to manipulate an module.
Whether it has something to do with the method or not.

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the angular.copy to duplicate your object:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy

Comment: do you have a syntax example ? i tried it this way : `$scope.setKunde = function (kunde) {
        var newKunde = angular.copy(kunde);
        calcFactory.setKunde(newKunde);
    };` and it still works in the same "false" way as before.